# Vert.x HttpClient doesn't reconnect to restarted server

Tags: java, netty, vert.x

I am using HttpClientRequest created through HttpClient to call either get or post on some http endpoints.

If the endpoint restarts, one of io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException or io.vertx.core.VertxException: Connection was closed.

Even after the endpoint is started again, all future requests will still fail. Exceptions might stop after a while, but it just doesn't work.

vert.x version: 3.4.2

OS: centOS 6

HttpClientOptions setup: protocol version HTTP_2, connection and idle timeout 2 seconds.

Comment: Are you attempting to reuse your HTTP request, by any chance?

Comment: No, I wasn't. The update of vert.x to 3.5.3 seems to have done the trick though and fixed everything.